# How can I create a Task wrapper or middleware in a netcore web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

This is a very common scenario in my solution:

```
    private IActionResult MyAction()
    {
        //Run in background
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {

                await //..
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception
            }
        });
        return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status200OK);
    }
```

So in all my actions I am repeating the same try catch with the same logging code, I am trying to do something like this:

```
    private IActionResult MyAction()
    {
        Task.Run(MyExceptionHandledAsyncTask(async () =>
        {
            await //..

        }));
        return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status200OK);
    }
```

Where MyExceptionHandledAsyncTask handles any exception in the task/action passed as parameter.

I have been trying but I am struggling with the returning data types and I am not sure how to do it.

How can I control this pattern and avoid repeating code?

Comment: There's no reason to wrap your try/catch in a Task.Run, you can just have the method itself return Task<IActionResult> and perform the await directly. Beyond that, you can capture your logging code in a method that takes an Exception parameter and use it in all your catches.

Comment: So what were your attempted solutions, and what about they wasn't working properly?

Comment: Exception handling and logging are cross-cutting concerns that can be delegated to middleware. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Controllers should be kept as lean as possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44791487/5233410

Comment: I already have a middleware at application level but it doesn't catch background exceptions outside the request scope

Comment: You shouldn't do any kind of these stuff inside an ASP.NET Application. If you are not extremely careful, with scoping of that Task you may end with your object and services being disposed **before** your Task.Run finishes it's work and no chance to report the error back to the user that the operation failed (since the request ended already)

Comment: That is why I am using a try catch with specific logging, the thing is that I need to make my response as fast as possible and do my work in background without using resources of the request context to avoid disposed objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a method that receives a **Func< Task >** as parameter:

```
public void Test()
{
    RunSafely(() => Task.Delay(2000));
}

public Task RunSafely(Func<Task> job)
    => Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            await job();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //todo 
        }
    });
```