# Application unhandled exceptions localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, globalization, asp.net-core-localization

I am trying to display error messages in locale language and for all handled exceptions my team is using resource file to display in local language but
Is there a way to intercept the middleware to display application **unhandled** exceptions in locale language?

Answer (score 1):

Standard .NET exceptions are localized and message language will depend on current thread culture. So for you to make it work you'll need to implement RequestCultureMiddleware that would change the language based on your needs. Here is an example:

```
public class RequestCultureMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public RequestCultureMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Get it from HTTP context as needed
        var language = "fr-FR";

        var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(language);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        await next(context);
    }
}
```

Register it **before MVC** in `Startup` class:

```
app.UseMiddleware(typeof(RequestCultureMiddleware));
app.UseMvc();
```

Please note: displaying exception message is not covered here.

Answer (score 0):

Near the start of our app we have a line of code that looks similar to

```
    config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new UnhandledExceptionHandler());
```

and this seems to catch errors.

We also have a catch-all route at the end of our route tables that looks a bit like

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "NotImplemented",
            routeTemplate: "{*data}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "notimplemented", data = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

where we call the same code.  You can check the Accept-Language header to make your best guess at what locale your caller might be able to use.  Re-post a specific question if you need help with that aspect.

Comment: Hey , thanks mate! but lets say I get the locale of the user, but how would I be able to change the exception message into that language?

Comment: @s-a-n  I think Andrei answered your question if you want the built-in support for system exceptions. Setting the thread locale near the start of your request. However you will need to be aware that users can (and do) send literally anything in the header values. You will need to validate the culture and possible select your best-guess or a good default. I also think showing platform exceptions with localized text is nearly useless. Do you really expect to them to debug your service? And why are you showing them exceptions anyway.  Localizing your app for errors will be a better use of time.

Comment: Yea I am trying to change the exceptions language from @Andrei's answer, still not luck. The only reason we want to throw the run time exceptions in the local language is that we have devs in a different country and we want them to be able to atleast get a jist of the exception as they dont read english.

Comment: I used to work on an App that used @andrei's answer.  Try registering a DelegatingHandler near the start of your pipeline that sets the UI Culture based on the caller's headers.  Waiting until an exception occurs is too late.