# How can I get the baseurl with UseExceptionHandler Startup mvc core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling

Say my website is hosted in the mywebsite folder of www.example.com/mywebsite and I visit 
http://www.example.com/mywebsite

It may be different for each host mywebsite
form exmple  www.example.com/mywebsite2

iam use Error Handling Assistance - UseExceptionHandler in Startup.cs My error view is in Views/home/Error.cshtml.

```
 app.UseExceptionHandler(errorHandlingPath: "/Home/Error");
```

but when error show url ddress:www.example.com/Home/Error .
i want show url http://www.example.com/mywebsite/Home/Error

Comment: You can get that info from [IExceptionHandlerPathFeature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics.iexceptionhandlerpathfeature), I found the answer here: the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791206/exception-handling-middleware-and-page